# Как передать текст динамически сгенерированной кнопки в функцию

Tags: python, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, qtablewidget, qpushbutton

У меня есть массив данных, которых я хочу вывести в `QTableWidget`. Для этого я в цикле `for` в каждом ряду создаю необходимые мне элементы для каждой колонки:

```
for row,i enumerate(data):
   # В этом месте я создаю другие элементы, которые не относятся к проблеме

    blockButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
    blockButton.setText(i['textForButton'])
    blockButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.blockChannel(blockButton.text()))
    self.ui.recommend_channelList.setCellWidget(row, 2, blockButton)
```

Я таблицу выводятся кнопки с уникальным текстом для каждой, но когда я нажимаю на кнопку и срабатывает вызов метода `blockChannel()`, в который я передаю текст кнопки, по которой я нажал:

```
def blockChannel(self, text):
    print(f"Полученный текст: {text}")
```

То `print` выводит текст самой последней кнопки из таблицы.
Я пробовал передавать значения в `text`, `accessibleDescription`, но результат всегда оставался прежним.

Как мне добиться передачи информации из данных кнопки, будь это текст или что-то другое, куда я могу поместить нужную мне информацию в функцию, которая должна быть выполнена по нажатию на неё? 
Напомню, что все кнопки генерируются в цикле.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожалуйста, всегда предоставляйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример.

Функция `lambda` должна выглядеть так:

```
        blockButton.clicked.connect(                                            
            lambda ch, text=blockButton.text(): self.blockChannel(text))
```

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        
        data =[{'textForButton': f'button_{i}'} for i in range(10)]
        
        table = QTableWidget(10, 3, self)
        table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["one", "two"])
        table.verticalHeader().hide()
        
        for row, i in enumerate(data):
           # В этом месте я создаю другие элементы, которые не относятся к проблеме

            blockButton = QPushButton()
            blockButton.setText(i['textForButton'])
            
# ---       blockButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.blockChannel(blockButton.text()))
# +++
            blockButton.clicked.connect(                                            # +++
                lambda ch, text=blockButton.text(): self.blockChannel(text))        # +++
            
            table.setCellWidget(row, 2, blockButton)            
            
        table.resizeColumnsToContents()
        table.resizeRowsToContents()
        
        grid_layout = QGridLayout(central_widget)
        grid_layout.addWidget(table, 0, 0)
   
    def blockChannel(self, text):
        print(f"Полученный текст: {text}")        
        QMessageBox.information(self, 'clicked', f'Вы нажали {text}')
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое. Ваш код работает, только я не могу понять, что такое "ch" в этой строчке кода:
lambda ch, text=blockButton.text(): self.blockChannel(text)

Comment: @ПростоАккаунт, checked - https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked